# MassTransit - Management of Consuming Messages (RabbitMq)

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'd like to know what is your suggested approach for managing the messages consume.
I'd like to be able to control the consumed messages, like stop \ pause \ resume.

Thanks,
Miri

Comment: You will start receiving messages when you start the bus and stop receiving and consuming them when you stop the bus. That's it.

Comment: Stopping the bus will stop the publish operations as well, which is not desired. In addition, the bus cannot be started again after it has been stopped.

Comment: You can publish still when the bus is stopped.

Comment: Just do the whole bus reconfiguration before starting it. Once you've stopped, throw away the old bus. Problem solved, honestly.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev : I want to pause specific queue. Stopping the bus will stop all queues?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by stopping queues, tbh.